# AWS SQS FIFO message doesn't seem to be retrying

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-sqs-fifo

I've set up a function to hit an API endpoint for a newly created entity that isn't immediately available.  If the endpoint returns a status of "pending", the function throws an error.  If the endpoint returns a status of "active", the function then deletes the SQS message and triggers several other microservices to do their things using SNS.  The SQS queue that triggers the function has a visibility timeout of 2 minutes, and the function itself has a 1 minute timeout.

**What I'm expecting to happen** is that if the endpoint returns a "pending" status, and the function throws an error, then after the 2 minute visibility timeout, the message would trigger the function again.  This should happen every 2 minutes until the api call returns an "active" status and the message is deleted, or until the message retention period is surpassed (currently 1 hour).  This seemed like a nice serverless way to poll my newly created entity to check if it was ready for other post-processing.

**What's actually happening** after adding a message to the SQS queue is that the CloudWatch logs are showing that the function is throwing an error like I'd expect, but the function is only being triggered one time.  I can't tell if the message is just not not visible for some reason, or if it somehow was deleted.  I don't know.  I'm am new to using SQS for a Lambda trigger, am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Be aware that if your Lambda function is warm-started for the 2nd invocation then the logs for the 2nd invocation will be in the same log stream as the first invocation. You might consider creating a simple test: create another SQS queue, connect it to a trivial Lambda function that simply prints the SQS message ID then throws an exception. Then use the awscli or console to review the status and visibility of that message.

Comment: @jarmod - I've reloaded the same log stream multiple times, and also checked for a new stream, and am not seeing another invocation anywhere.  I'll try a scaled down approach and see what I can see.

Comment: I just set up the basic example I suggested earlier, albeit with a non-FIFO queue, and I see the same SQS message delivered to the Lambda function every 2 minutes, and so far they're all logged in the same log stream. I expect this to continue until I hit the max receive count on the redrive policy (defaults to 10, so 20 minutes) at which point I expect the message to be moved to the associated DLQ. Do you have a configured DLQ and maximum receives set to 1?

Comment: And identical, correct behavior with FIFO queue.

Comment: @jarmod - thanks for looking into it for me.  It was a dumb mistake.  I didn't realize the error was being caught and logged, not actually thrown.  I think I learned something though.  It looks like if using SQS as a trigger, and the function doesn't throw an error or timeout, then the SQS message is automatically deleted from the queue.  Is that right?  I hadn't seen that in any documentation anywhere...

Comment: Yes, and that behavior is [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html): "If your function successfully processes the batch, Lambda deletes the messages from the queue." You can optionally delete the message too, but the Lambda service will delete it for you (if the batch of messages succeeds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possible causes here:

1. your Lambda function handler did not actually throw an exception to the Lambda runtime environment, so Lambda thought the function had successfully processed the message and the Lambda service then deleted the message from the queue (so that it would not get processed again)
2. your SQS queue has a configured DLQ with maximum receives set to 1, so the message is delivered once, the Lambda function fails, and the message is subsequently moved to the DLQ
3. the SQS message *was* re-delivered to the Lambda function and was logged but the logs were made to an earlier log stream (because this invocation was warm) and so it wasn't obvious that the Lambda function had actually been invoked multiple times with the same failed message

To verify this all works normally, I set up a simple test with both FIFO and non-FIFO queues and configured the queues to trigger a Lambda function that simply logged the SQS message and then threw an exception. As expected, I saw the same SQS message delivered to the Lambda function every 2 minutes (which is the queue's message visibility timeout). That continued until it hit the max receive count on the SQS redrive policy (defaults to 10 attempts) at which point the failed message was correctly moved to the associated DLQ.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod.  My issue was that I didn't realize that a successful invocation of the function resulted in the message batch automatically being deleted from the queue.  My error was actually being caught elsewhere in my application.  So even though my code wasn't deleting the message, because there wasn't an error being thrown, the invocation was "successful" and the message was getting deleted.  I removed the try/catch and it's working as expected now.